# How to use obj.init in my document.getElements?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to this framework and I am just converting my javascript/jquery to ajax.

I have this code:

```
var Obj = {
    Init:function(config){
        this.config = config;
        this.BindEvents();
    },
    BindEvents:function(){
        $this = Obj.config;
        Obj.ReturnArray();
    },
    ReturnArray:function(){
        $this = Obj.config;

        for(x = 0; x < itemNames.length; x++){
            var obj = {itemName:itemNames[x],itemPrice:itemPrices[x]};
            console.log(obj);
            prods.push(obj);
        }

        for(var ctr = 0; ctr < prods.length; ctr++){
            var rows = parseInt(document.getElementById("modalTable").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].rows.length);
            var table = document.getElementById("modalTable").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
        }
    }
}

Obj.Init({
    modalTable       : $("#modalTable"),
    mainTable        : $("#mainTable"),
    btnAddToTable    : $("btnAddToTable"),
    mainCellQuantity : $(".mainCellQuantity"),
    mainTBody        : $("#mainTBody")
});
```

But I want to you use the object being initialized in `Obj.Init({});`

```
var rows = parseInt(document.getElementById("modalTable").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].rows.length);
var table = document.getElementById("modalTable").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
```

just to be like this

```
var rows = parseInt(modalTable.mainTbody.rows.length);
```

To sum it all, I want all javascript's `document` be `objects`. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I am by phone so cannot try it.

In my understanding you want that all the dom elements inherit from your Obj.

Considering that all the document objects inherit from Element, what you could try is to extend the Element prototype with your prototype.

It could be something like:

```
Element.prototype = Object.create(Obj.prototype);
```

Comment: I was about to answer my own question sir since someone helped me. I actually got it using jquery.each()

Answer (score 0):

So, someone suggested to use `jquery.each()` so I tried, and luckily, I solved my problem. I'll share my answer so anyone might see this helpful

```
$.each(prods_(this_is_the_array)_, function(index){
    var row = modalTBody_(the_tbody)_.insertRow(index);
});
```